# How can I get my GA to converge?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, combinatorics

I'm trying to write a GA to solve the following puzzle...

[image]

A binary encoding is (I think) very efficient. Each piece can be:

- the original way up or flipped - 1 bit
- rotated by 0 (ie none), 90, 180 or 270 degs - 2 bits
- at position (x, y), where x and y go from 0 to 7 - 3 bits for each co-ordinate

This means that each piece's orientation and position can be encoded in 9 bits, making a total of 117 bits for the whole puzzle.

The fitness is calculated by placing each piece in the frame, ignoring any parts that lie out of the frame, and then adding up the number of empty squares. When that hits zero, we have a solution.

I have some standard GA methods I've used in other code (which I'll paste in below), but I can't seem to get it to converge. The fitness drops to about 11 (give or take), but never seems to go any lower. I've tried fiddling with the parameters, but can't get it any better.

At the risk of posting too much code, I'll show what I've got (where it seems relevant). If anyone can give me some idea how I could improve, it would be great. This is all in C#, but it should be clear enough to people who use other languages.

After generating an initial population of 1000 chromosomes (code not shown as it's just generating random binary strings of length 117), I enter the main loop, where on each generation, I call the Breed method, passing in the current population and some parameters...

```
private static List<Chromosome> Breed(List<Chromosome> population, int crossoverGene, 
                  double mutationProbability, double mutationRate) {
  List<Chromosome> nextGeneration = new List<Chromosome>();
  // Cross breed half of the population number
  for (int nChromosome = 0; nChromosome < population.Count / 2; nChromosome++) {
    Chromosome daddy = Roulette(population);
    Chromosome mummy = Roulette(population);
    string babyGenes = daddy.Genes.Substring(0, crossoverGene)
                     + mummy.Genes.Substring(crossoverGene);
    Chromosome baby = new Chromosome(babyGenes);
    baby.Fitness = Fitness(baby);
    nextGeneration.Add(baby);
  }
  // Mutate some chromosomes
  int numberToMutate = (int)(P() * 100 * mutationProbability);
  List<Chromosome> mutatedChromosomes = new List<Chromosome>();
  for (int i = 0; i < numberToMutate; i++) {
    Chromosome c = Roulette(population);
    string mutatedGenes = MutateGenes(c.Genes, mutationRate);
    Chromosome mutatedChromosome = new Chromosome(mutatedGenes);
    mutatedChromosome.Fitness = Fitness(mutatedChromosome);
    mutatedChromosomes.Add(mutatedChromosome);
  }
  // Get the next generation from the fittest chromosomes
  nextGeneration = nextGeneration
    .Union(population)
    .Union(mutatedChromosomes)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Fitness)
    .Take(population.Count)
    .ToList();
  return nextGeneration;
}
```

MutateGenes just flips bits at random, based on the mutation rate passed in. The main loop continues until we either hit the maximum number of generations, or the fitness drops to zero. I'm currently running for 1000 generations.

Here's the roulette method...

```
private static Chromosome Roulette(List<Chromosome> population) {
  double totalFitness = population.Sum(c => 1 / c.Fitness);
  double targetProbability = totalFitness * P();
  double cumProbability = 0.0;
  List<Chromosome> orderedPopulation = population.OrderBy(c => c.Fitness).ToList();
  for (int i = 0; i < orderedPopulation.Count; i++) {
    Chromosome c = orderedPopulation[i];
    cumProbability += 1 / c.Fitness;
    if (cumProbability > targetProbability) {
      return c;
    }
  }
  return orderedPopulation.Last();
}
```

Don't know if you need to see any of the other code. I was a bit wary about posting too much in case it put people off!

Anyone able to make any suggestions as to how I can get this to improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todor Balabanov's answer is very interesting. Probably using relative coordinates and a proper packing function is the keystone.

Anyway I'd like to expand upon your idea as much as possible. A full discussion is probably too long for Stackoverflow...

#### TL;DR

1. Binary encoding does not give you any advantage.
2. The chosen alphabet isn't the smallest that permits a natural expression of the problem.
3. Considering the full range of coordinates (`[0;7] x [0;7]`) for every piece is excessive (and somewhat misleading for fitness evaluation).

   Points (2) and (3) allow to reduce the search space from `2^117` to `2^95` elements.
4. A more informative fitness function is a great help.

   - You can use a multi-value fitness score, penalizing configurations that present holes.
   - Squares covered by overlapping pieces shouldn't be counted: an illegal configuration cannot have a fitness greater than a legal one.
5. [ALPS](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a971/bb2c2cee841702b033cd01bc79f8e35b7893.pdf) can reduce the problem of premature convergence (reference implementation [here](https://github.com/ghornby/alps)).

---

I've have elaborated on these points in a [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/morinim/vita/wiki/polyomino_tutorial) (it's a work in progress).

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! I'm going to need to read your code more carefully, as I'm a C# programmer, and find C++ difficult to read, however, I see your approach. Thanks for spending the time to write up such a comprehensive article.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you use genetic algorithms framework like Apache GA Framework you can implement chromosomes as list of shapes and you can use permutation crossover and mutation.
2. You will have blank spaces, which you will try to minimize (reduce them to 0). It is not a problem that you will have blanks, just count them and include them as penalty component in the fitness function.
3. Generally GAs are not so strong in combinatorial problems. I did many experiments like solving Rubik’s Cube with GA or solving Puzzle 15 with GA. Another experiment was 2D Optimal Cutting Problem with GA. If you are interested I can provide you the research papers and source code (GitHub). GAs are good giving you sub-optimal solution, but they are not good in giving you the optimal solution, which is even harder when it is a combinatorial problem.
4. The size of the population is an open question. You should do convergence investigation with different populations. Bigger population does not mean better and faster solution. Even 100 is too much for most of the problems solved with GA.
5. If you use absolute coordinates you will need to handle x and y, which is too complicated. Imagine that you support list of shapes. Packing procedure can get shape by shape and place each shape as close as possible to already handled shapes. It will speed-up your convergence.

   ```
   /**
    * Pack function which uses bounding rectangle of the polygons in the sheet
    * with specified dimensions.
    * 
    * @param width
    *            Sheet width.
    * @param height
    *            Sheet height.
    */
   public void pack1(int width, int height) {
       int level[] = new int[width];
       for (int i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
           level[i] = 0;
       }

       /*
        * Insure pieces width according sheet width.
        */
       for (Piece piece: population.get(worstIndex)) {
           if (piece.getWidth() > width) {
               piece.flip();
           }
       }

       /*
        * Pack pieces.
        */
       int x = 0;
       int y = 0;
       for (Piece piece: population.get(worstIndex)) {
           if (x + (int) piece.getWidth() >= width) {
               x = 0;
           }

           /*
            * Find y offset for current piece.
            */
           y = 0;
           for (int dx = x; dx < (x + piece.getWidth()); dx++) {
               if (dx < width && y < level[dx]) {
                   y = level[dx];
               }
           }

           // TODO Check the delta after subtraction.
           /*
            * Set current piece coordinates.
            */
           piece.moveX(x - piece.getMinX());
           piece.moveY(y - piece.getMinY());

           /*
            * Move lines for next placement.
            */
           for (int dx = x; dx < (x + piece.getWidth()); dx++) {
               if (dx < width) {
                   level[dx] = (int)(y + piece.getHeight());
               }
           }

           // TODO Some strange behavior with the rotation.
           x += (int) piece.getWidth() + 1;
       }
   }

   /**
    * Pack function which uses exact boundaries of the polygons in the sheet
    * with specified dimensions.
    * 
    * @param width
    *            Sheet width.
    * @param height
    *            Sheet height.
    */
   public void pack2(int width, int height) {
       /*
        * Pieces already placed on the sheet.
        */
       List < Piece > front = new ArrayList < Piece > ();

       /*
        * Virtual Y boundary.
        */
       double level = 0;

       /*
        * Place all pieces on the sheet
        */
       for (Piece current: population.get(worstIndex)) {
           double bestLeft = 0;
           double bestTop = level;
           current.moveX(-current.getMinX());
           current.moveY(-current.getMinY() + level);

           /*
            * Move across sheet width.
            */
           while (current.getMaxX() < width) {
               /*
                * Touch sheet bounds of touch other piece.
                */
               while (current.getMinY() > 0 && Util.overlap(current, front) == false) {
                   current.moveY(-1);
               }
               // TODO Plus one may be is wrong if the piece should be part of
               // the area.
               current.moveY(+2);

               /*
                * Keep the best found position.
                */
               if (current.getMinY() < bestTop) {
                   bestTop = current.getMinY();
                   bestLeft = current.getMinX();
               }

               /*
                * Try next position on right.
                */
               current.moveX(+1);
           }

           /*
            * Put the piece in the best available coordinates.
            */
           current.moveX(-current.getMinX() + bestLeft);
           current.moveY(-current.getMinY() + bestTop);

           /*
            * Shift sheet level if the current piece is out of previous bounds.
            */
           if (current.getMaxY() > level) {
               level = current.getMaxY() + 1;
           }

           /*
            * Add current piece in the ordered set and the front set.
            */
           front.add(current);
       }
   }

   /**
    * Pack function which uses exact boundaries of the polygons in the sheet
    * with specified dimensions.
    * 
    * @param width
    *            Sheet width.
    * @param height
    *            Sheet height.
    */
   public void pack3(int width, int height) {
       Polygon stack = new Polygon(
           GEOMETRY_FACTORY
           .createLinearRing(new Coordinate[] {
               new Coordinate(0, -2, 0), new Coordinate(width - 1, -2, 0),
                   new Coordinate(width - 1, 0, 0), new Coordinate(0, 0, 0), new Coordinate(0, -2, 0)
           }),
           null, GEOMETRY_FACTORY);

       /*
        * Virtual Y boundary.
        */
       double level = stack.getEnvelopeInternal().getMaxX();

       /*
        * Place all pieces on the sheet
        */
       for (Piece current: population.get(worstIndex)) {
           double bestLeft = 0;
           double bestTop = level;
           current.moveX(-current.getMinX());
           current.moveY(-current.getMinY() + level);

           /*
            * Move across sheet width.
            */
           while (current.getMaxX() < width) {
               /*
                * Touch sheet bounds of touch other piece.
                */
               while (current.getMinY() > 0 && Util.overlap(current, stack) == false) {
                   current.moveY(-1);
               }
               // TODO Plus one may be is wrong if the piece should be part of
               // the area.
               current.moveY(+2);

               /*
                * Keep the best found position.
                */
               if (current.getMinY() < bestTop) {
                   bestTop = current.getMinY();
                   bestLeft = current.getMinX();
               }

               /*
                * Try next position on right.
                */
               current.moveX(+1);
           }

           /*
            * Put the piece in the best available coordinates.
            */
           current.moveX(-current.getMinX() + bestLeft);
           current.moveY(-current.getMinY() + bestTop);

           /*
            * Shift sheet level if the current piece is out of previous bounds.
            */
           if (current.getMaxY() > level) {
               level = current.getMaxY() + 1;
           }

           /*
            * Add current piece in the ordered set and the front set.
            */
           stack = (Polygon) SnapOverlayOp.union(stack, current.getPolygon()).getBoundary().convexHull();
           stack.normalize();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Very interesting approach. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm interested to know more about why GAs aren't good for this sort of problem. I've seen GA tutorials where they used them to solve the travelling salesman problem, which is combinatorial. My thought was that my problem (the way I coded it) has about 2x10E35 combinations, but the fitness function only has 64 distinct values. (to be continued...)

Comment: Seems to me that this itself would cause a major issue. However well you cross and mutate the genes, the chances of finding a gene string that has a better fitness is vanishingly small, something like 64 in 2x10E35, which is about as close to zero as makes no difference. Does that make any sense?

Comment: To be combinatorial does not mean that both problems are comparable. Some of the problems are harder than the others. Imagine it as [2D wave function](http://slideplayer.com/slide/4751950/15/images/23/Particle+in+a+2D/3D+box+Particle+in+a+2D+box+is+exactly+the+same+analysis,+just+ignore+z.+What+do+all+these+wave+functions+look+like.jpg) in which you are looking for an optimum. Function on the left is easier than function on the right.

Comment: @Todor Yes, but in both of those cases, you have a continuous function, so even if the next generation contains a gene that is a teeny bit better, it's an improvement. With my case, the chances of hitting a better gene are almost zero, basically 64 out of 2x10E35.

Comment: It was only schematic explanation. When the function is discrete the situation is not so different. Some functions are harder than the others. What you can do is running parallel instances of GA and exchange chromosomes between them at some point in time. The other think you can do is introducing new chromosome in the population when there is no improvement for certain amount of generations. When even this not help you can combine GA with some other optimization techniques. GAs have there own limit in such optimization challenges.

Comment: The other thing is that suboptimal solution for TSP is well accepted when suboptimal solutions in puzzles are not so well accepted. You can observe what kind of suboptimal solutions I get in the [Puzzle 15](https://github.com/TodorBalabanov/genetic-algorithms-for-puzzle-15/tree/master/eu/veldsoft/puzzle/fifteen).

Answer (score 1):

You have a very interesting problem to solve. I like it very much. First of all it is a combinatorial problem, which can be very hard to solve with the classical genetic algorithms. I have some comments, but they are my subjective opinion: 1) Binary encoding does not give you any advantage (only overhead for encoding and decoding), you can use C# objects; 2) It is not smart to ignore pieces outside of the frame; 3) You will be trapped in local optimum all the time, this is the nature of genetic algorithms; 4) Population size of 1K is too much, use something smaller; 5) Do not use absolute x-y coordinates, use relative coordinates and proper packing function.

Comment: Thx for the comments. 1) How would I do this with C# objects? 2) Why not, they leave blank spaces inside the frame, which are counted as part of the fitness. 3) Is that specifically here, or generally with GA? I know GA can get trapped in local minima, that's why we have a large enough population to explore the solution space. 4) 1K is only the initial population, which is immediately cut down to the working population size of 100 chromosomes. Forgot to make that clear, so will edit the question. 5) What's the advantage with rel co-ords, and what do you mean by a "proper packing function"? Thx